# How do I change / show different CSS while a service is called / responds in Javascript AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to show a different CSS style on my HTML FORM before my code consults a service and, on its response, change it back again. I'm using `ng-class` to dynamically add the class whenever the `activeload1` boolean is on true. Sadly this never gets reflected on my HTML. I purposely made the service call reach an exception to see if the class change happens then and it does (it just hangs on the load css since it never reaches the class deactivation due to the exception). How can I reflect the CSS class change/addition on my HTML? The code seems to just assign the `true` value to the `activeload1` boolean consult the service and then assigning `false` again without reflecting anything. My code:

HTML:

```
<div id="divPrincipal" class="wrapper" ng-class="{loading1:bravosCtrl.activeload1}"> </div>
```

Snippet of funtion in JS. file:

```
    this.buscar = function(){            
        this.activeload1 = true;
        if (this.busqueda){
            this.usuarioService.buscarUsuario(this.busqueda,this.userSession).then((usuariosE) => {
                console.log("SUCCESS");
            });
            this.activeload1=false;
        }else{
            this.activeload1=false;
            this.searchError = true;
        }
    };
```

CSS :

```
.wrapper {
border-radius: 10px;
background: #24CDD1;
padding: 25px;
max-width: 680px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
box-shadow: 2px 8px 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
position: relative;
}

.wrapper.loading1::before {
content: '';
background: url('https://i.imgur.com/sdK5jNw.gif') no-repeat center center;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 9999;
}
.wrapper.loading1::after {
content: '';
background: #24CDD1;
display: inline-block;
opacity: .65;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Is your service class using the angularJS `$http` service to retrieve data? If not, angular may not know that anything has changed when the service call finishes.

Comment: Hell, thanks for your time. Yes I am using $http in the service.

Comment: In that case, the answer from @joohong89 looks correct. Angular should recalculate state after the HTTP call completes, and the UI should update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the $http service request is asynchronous. From the code, you are assigning `activeload1` to false immediately without waiting for the http response to come back.

To set `activeload1` to false when the $http service respond, simply add it to the success callback function.

```
this.usuarioService.buscarUsuario(this.busqueda,this.userSession).then((usuariosE) => {
     console.log("SUCCESS");
     this.activeload1=false; // added here
});
```